# How to count number of rows while using UNION in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$where = "tag = '".$tag."'";
$this->db->where($where);
$query1 = $this->db->get();
$result1 = $query1->num_rows();

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table2');
$where = "tag = '".$tag."'";
$this->db->where($where);
$query2 = $this->db->get();
$result2 = $query2->num_rows();

$result = $result1+$result2;
return $result;
```

In this question, I have two tables `table1 and table2` where the tables structure of both are same. Now, I want to count number of rows. Now, it showing me wrong count data. If `tag` data present in first table then it counts `1` and if `tag` data present in both table then it counts `2`. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your query is ok and each one returns the exact result you need, And now you just wanna get num of rows only then its better to use `count_all_results()` .. and be on the safe side and reset the query builder before making another query:

```
...
$r1= $this->db->count_all_results();
$this->db->reset_query();
...
$r2= $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Both of them should return the count of results if your query is alright, then simply add them:

```
$sum = $r1 + $r2;
```